# SQL select data from lookup table with 2 tables and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

If I query by '08' will search from in table1 id_code1 at position 3
then will be got which id_code1 contains '08' then select data from table2 and got id_code2 to select data from table3

I have 3 tables,
Table 1. contains id_code1 and id_code2 which are a string

**table1**

```
id_code1  |   id_code2
----------+--------------
1008SD7X  |    M71X456700
1008DG5B  |    N71X456800
100894EX  |    P71X456900
1064TESE  |    Q71X456135
19745EGS  |    R71X456789
10DFEE77  |    S71X456239
1EERSD7X  |    S86X436477
```

**table2** contains id_code1, data1, data2, data3

```
id_code1  |   data1  |  data2  |  data3  |
----------+----------+---------+---------+
1008SD7X  |   12.9   |  10     |   7.5   |
1008DG5B  |   13.8   |  10     |   4.2   |
100894EX  |   15.4   |  11     |   3.0   |
1064TESE  |   12.7   |  12     |   2.5   |
19745EGS  |   14.2   |  12     |   5.5   |
10DFEE77  |   12.5   |  11     |   4.7   |
1EERSD7X  |   15.5   |  10     |   3.5   |
```

**table3** contains id_code2, data4, data5, data6

```
id_code1   | data4  |  data5  | data6 |
-----------+--------+---------+-------+
M71X456700 |   29   |  11     |   5   |
N71X456800 |   38   |  18     |   2   |
P71X456900 |   34   |  11     |   3   |
Q71X456135 |   47   |  12     |   5   |
R71X456789 |   12   |  14     |   5   |
S71X456239 |   15   |  11     |   4   |
S86X436477 |   15   |  19     |   3   |
```

Now I cannot select table3 with table2

```
select table3.* from table3
where table3.id_code2 in 
        ( select table1.id_code2 
        from table1 where 
        locate('08',table1.id_code1)=3)
```

```
id_code1   | data4  |  data5  | data6 |
-----------+--------+---------+-------+
M71X456700 |   29   |  11     |   5   |
N71X456800 |   38   |  18     |   2   |
P71X456900 |   34   |  11     |   3   |
```

I expect the result like this

```
id_code1  | id_code2  |  data1 |  data2  | data3  |  data4 | data5  | data6 
----------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------
1008SD7X  |M71X456700 | 12.9   |  10     |   7.5  |  29   |  11     |   5   |
1008DG5B  |N71X456800 | 13.8   |  10     |   4.2  |  38   |  18     |   2   |
100894EX  |P71X456900 | 15.4   |  11     |   3.0  |  34   |  11     |   3   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
SELECT  t1.id_code1,
        t1.id_code2,
        t2.data1,
        t2.data2,
        t2.data3,
        t3.data4,
        t3.data5,
        t3.data6
  FROM  table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id_code1 = t1.id_code1
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id_code2 = t1.id_code2
  WHERE LOCATE('08', t1.id_code1) = 3;
```

This returns all rows from `table1` that match your `WHERE` clause, joins to `table2` and `table3` and returns the appropriate columns from those tables.

Results:

```
id_code1  id_code2    data1  data2  data3  data4  data5  data6
1008SD7X  M71X456700  12.9   10     7.5    29     11     5
1008DG5B  N71X456800  13.8   10     4.2    38     18     2
100894EX  P71X456900  15.4   11     3      34     11     3
```

**Note that I have changed the name of `id_code1` to `id_code2` in `table3` because I assumed that this was due to a typo.**

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77703/1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to join `table1` with both `table2` and `table3`:

```
select
  t1.id_code1, t1.id_code2,
  t2.data1, t2.data2, t2.data3,
  t3.data4, t3.data5, t3.data6
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id_code1 = t1.id_code1
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id_code2 = t1.id_code2
```